# Integral regarding payoff

Tags: definite-integrals, finance

Hey Guys I'm a bit stuck on trying to solve the following integral

$$\int_0^6 e^{ \frac{(\ln s - \ln y + c_1)^2}{C_2} } + S( 6 - S) \frac{dy}{y}$$

Overall what I'm trying to figure is how to price an option with using black sholes equation ?

$$ payoff= max(s(6-s),0) $$

Comment: That is NOT the correct integral to price that option.  If you are familiar with Margrabe's closed-form for a spread option, then you have a special case here with $S_2=6S$ and $S_1=S^2$.

Comment: Why is not the correct integral for this option ? What would be the correct form ? Sorry I'm not familiar with Margrabe form

Comment: You've added $S(6-S)$ as part of the integrand.  In addition, the integration variable you've written is $y$ while the payoff function is given in terms of $S$.